# How can I log the failed cases of selenium ide and send them to an email using selenium ide commands

Tags: selenium-ide

I need a command that helps me to find a solution for the following problem:

logging the failed cases of selenium ide and send them to an email using selenium ide commands.

Thanks.
Omar

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following URL to execute Selenium-IDE HTML Scripts using Selenium RC. Using this you will get HTML result file. To get screenshot you can add captureScreenshot command after failed step.

http://www.softwaretestingdiary.com/2012/02/selenium-core-setup-to-execute-selenium.html